# Access Nintex Workflow Variable through code

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

Can we access the value of nintex workflow variable from C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can not access Nintex variable through code outside the Workflow context.
Here are the posts from Nintex connect to further clarify.

http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/7760.aspx

http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/12129.aspx